# How to use Role Provider in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, roleprovider

I am first time using Membership and Role provider for my login page.My membership was work fine but I couldn't able to use role provider on my login page.
I have one controller named MyAccount controller. This controller will verify user membership and after verified it will redirect to Home controller based on user Role.
Here is

> MyAccount controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(Login l, string returnUrl = "")
    {if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var isValidUser = Membership.ValidateUser(l.UserName, l.Password);
            if (isValidUser)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(l.UserName, l.RememberMe);
                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }

               else If(*"USER ROLE AS ADMIN"*)
                {
                    RedirectToAction("AdminIndex","Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    RedirectToAction("ClientIndex","Home");
                }

            }
        }
        ViewBag.ErrorMassage = "Wrong Id or Password";
        ModelState.Remove("Password");
        return View();
    }
```

And

> Home Controller:

```
[Authorize (Roles= "Admin")]
    public ActionResult AdminIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize (Roles = "Client")]
    public ActionResult ClientIndex()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I am not sure Where I should check for User Role, In MyAccount Controller or In Home Controller?

> RoleProvider:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //check cache
        var cacheKey = string.Format("{0}_role", username);
        if (HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey] != null)
        {
            return (string[])HttpRuntime.Cache[cacheKey];
        }
        string[] roles = new string[] { };
        roles = gateway.GetUserRole(username);
        {

            if (roles.Any())
            {
                HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheKey, roles, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_cacheTimeoutInMinute), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);

            }
        }
        return roles;
    }
 public override bool IsUserInRole(string username, string roleName)
    {
        var userRoles = GetRolesForUser(username);
        return userRoles.Contains(roleName);
    }
```

How can I Use this RoleProvider to my controller and redirect it to Admin or Client Action?

Answer (score 0):

Register your custom role provider in `web.config`:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="MyNamespace.MyRoleProvider, MyAssembly" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Update `Login` action method on the `MyAccount` controller:

```
if (Roles.IsUserInRole("Admin"))
```